# Profiling short-lived threads? Sometimes getting sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 3 (No such process)

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I use the perf command to analyze program performance, the execution command is

```
perf stat -p 4124093 -- sleep 5
```

where 4124093 is pid.
Then I get an error message

```
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 3 (No such process) for event (cpu-clock).
/bin/dmesg | grep -i perf may provide additional information.
```

Not every execution of the 'perf' command will result in this error. Only when the program(pid:4124093) runs **too busy**, this error will occur.

I have looked up the information, and the reason is some threads in my program are short lived. Due to the short lifespan of the thread, perf didn't have a chance to start collecting data before the thread terminated, which resulted in this error.
(Refer to https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ca8000684ec4e66f965e1f9547a3c6cb834154ca)

> While monitoring a multithread process with pid option,  perf sometimes may return sys_perf_event_open failure with 3(No such process) **if any of the process's threads die before  we open the event**.

However, I still haven't found a solution to this problem. Does anyone know?

Comment: Does this race condition happen only as `perf` starts, or is it an ongoing problem for threads that get created after `perf` attaches?

Comment: The phenomenon I observed is that the error occurs as soon as perf is launched. As for whether these short-lived threads are created before or after perf attach, I am not quite sure. If this process keeps creating and destroying threads continuously, both of these situations could potentially exist.

Comment: If it's just a startup problem, it's not really anything to worry about.  It'll be able to trace all the other threads created during the 5 seconds that your profile runs for.  So the question is whether it *only* happens right as perf starts, or if it can also happen with a process that doesn't start spawning threads until after perf is already attached.  A simple experiment would be to run `perf stat ./test` to start the thing under perf instead of attaching.